# Does the UA Barbarian Path of the Beast Claw Add the Strength Modifier to Damage?

Tags: dnd-5e, unearthed-arcana, barbarian

I was looking through the options for the 3rd level Path of Beast feature, Form of the Beast, and I noticed *no mention for any damage modifiers* on hit.

> Claws. Your hands transform into claws, which
> deal 1d6 slashing damage on a hit. ([UA 2020, Pg. 1](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/UA2020-Subclasses01.pdf))

In comparison to this, the Aarakocra race gives you the Talons, specifically mentioning the **damage value + the Strength modifier**.

> **Talons.** 
> Your talons are natural weapons, which you can use to make unarmed strikes. If you hit with them, you deal slashing damage equal to **1d4 + your Strength modifier**, instead of the bludgeoning damage normal for an unarmed strike. ([DND Beyond](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/aarakocra#AarakocraTraits))

I am curious about this, because in [another question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/176504/can-you-wield-a-greataxe-and-claws-with-the-ua-barbarian-path-of-the-beast), people have asked about the claws in an attack action, referencing damage values to include the Strength modifier.

> ---- Take Attack Action ----
> attack with Greataxe (1d12+2+STR) 
> attack with Claw (1d6+2+STR)
> attack with Claw (1d6+2+STR)
> (From [Can you wield a Greataxe and Claws...?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/176504/can-you-wield-a-greataxe-and-claws-with-the-ua-barbarian-path-of-the-beast))

Comment: It might be worth holding off answering this for another week until Tasha's Cauldron, which will feature the official release for Path of the Beast, comes out. I guess we could answer this question strictly with the understanding that it only pertains to the the deprecated UA version....

Comment: I'm asking now since I'm creating a character for a game tonight, so my time-sensitive decisions may be affected by the answer. I just want to know if there's any reason other people on this site have interpreted the Claws to include the Strength modifier, or if that was just a mistake (I want to make things easy for my DM if there's a question).

Comment: Fair enough! The answers could always be edited to add a note about the published version as well, or a new question could be asked if the feature was changed enough in the published version to warrant its own separate question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Yes, you add your Strength modifier.

The rules for [attack and damage rolls with a melee weapon](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/using-ability-scores#Strength) say:

> You add your Strength modifier to your attack roll and your damage roll when attacking with a melee weapon

The UA Beast Barbarian’s Form of the Beast feature says:

> Until your rage ends, you manifest a **natural melee weapon**, choosing one of the following options each time you rage:

Your claws are a melee weapon, so you add your strength modifier to the damage.

Answer (score 2):

### Yes, they add their Strength modifier to claw attacks

The description of [Strength](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/using-ability-scores#Strength) rules states:

> You add your Strength modifier to your attack roll and your damage roll when attacking with a **melee weapon** [...]

All weapons created by Form of the Beast are natural weapons, so you add your Strength modifier.

Answer (score 1):

## You add your strength modifier

The official release of *Tasha's Cauldron of Everything* has reworked the description of Form of the Beast to clarify that your Strength modifier is used. It now reads:

> Until the rage ends, you manifest a natural weapon. It counts as a simple melee weapon for you, and **you add your Strength modifier to the attack and damage rolls when you attack with it, as normal**.

This applies to Bite, Claws, and Tail.

Comment: Tasha's didnt change the UA material. This question is about UA material, not the subclass printed in Tasha's.

Comment: Awesome! This answers my question, and the updated info from Tasha's Cauldron of Everything further solidifies the justification to add the strength mod to the damage rolls.